# create a common routine callable from razor with DbContext and DI

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I want to create a common routine where I can pass in a key and in that routine I pull out the value for that key.  If the key isn't there, I pull it from a DB and cache it.

In the example below, `Resources` is a class with the static member, `ConfigDisplay`.  Since it's static, I don't have my usual dependencies being injected in (like I could have with a Controller - httpcontext, services, repos, etc).

What is a better way to call a method from razor that needs access to my DbContext?   In a nutshell, I need to configure the text of a label or button, or anything else, and during the first request of that page, I pull it from my database and cache it for further requests.  Seems like a simple problem, just not getting my head wrapped around it right!

```
<div>
    <input id="searchnode" type="text" placeholder="@Resources.ConfigDisplay("mykey")" />
</div> 


Inside my helper class, Resources:
 static public string ConfigDisplay(sting key)
    {  // Need DbContext here to pull out value for "key" if it doesn't exist }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, the best of which depends on where and how often you need this value:

1. [Custom action filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.0#action-filters)

   You can create a custom action filter that is injected with your context, retrieves the value, and then sets it in something like `ViewBag`. You'd then need only add the attribute to any controller/action that needed the value, and it would be there waiting for you where you stored it (i.e. `ViewBag`). This could also be applied globally in your Startup.cs.
2. [Tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

   You can create a tag helper that is injected with your context and retrieves the value. The nice part about this approach is that you could potentially generalize it somewhat to allow for varying values to to be retrieved. For example, you could have a tag helper that accesses a settings table and returns a particular setting like:

   ```
   <setting key="MySetting" />
   ```

   And, once Razor finished rendering the view, it would just have the  value of that setting there instead of your custom tag.
3. [View component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

   You can create a view component that renders a partial with your value. This is a good approach if the value is always used in creating some standard bit of HTML. Instead of copying this HTML all over the place, you can just call the view component, which will fetch the value and then render the appropriate bit of HTML and dump the whole shebang on your page. Again, you'd inject it with your context to allow it retrieve the value.

In all three cases above, the caching bit is really secondary and would be handled the same regardless of which approach you took. Generally, you would configure an `IDistributedCache` in your Startup.cs and then inject `IDistributeCache` along with your context. You attempt to retrieve value from cache first, and if it's not present, then you query your context and persist it to your cache.

Comment: I like the approach of the Tag helper.  I'm trying to create one, but it's not stopping at my breakpoint.  What would be the syntax of a tag helper where I pass in a key?  I want it to render a string based on a passed in value.  Where do I put my passed in value in this was my taghelper?   <mytaghelper></mytaghelper>

Comment: tag helper attributes are bound to public properties on your tag helper. So, for something like a `key` attribute, you'd need a property like `Key` on your tag helper class. Alternatively, you can name it whatever you like and then use `[HtmlAttributeName("key")]` on the property to bind it to the `key` attribute.

Comment: Additionally, since something like `key` with this example tag helper would be pretty much required in order for it to work correctly, you can enforce that via the `HtmlTargetElement` attribute. For example, you could add something like `[HtmlTargetElement("setting", Attributes = "key")]` to the class.

Comment: Super!  got it working, thank you so much Chris.  Hats of to you from my team here...